# Is it possible to use 2 different kinds of ram(ddr2 and dimm) on a motherboard?

Tags: memory

Will they be compatible to run on a motherboard supporting 2gb of memory?
Will there be any effect on the system performance or any other components?

Comment: what do you mean? DIMM is a package type; DDR2 is a RAM technology.  DIMMs can be DDR2 or DDR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **DIMM**, or dual in-line memory module, can be any of the following:

**SDR SDRAM**

**DDR SDRAM**

**DDR2 SDRAM**

**DDR3 SDRAM**

for more information please post make and model of the mainboard and memory you want to use.

edit: the specs are pretty clear on the typ of memory the can be used with your mainboard:

- Dual Channel DDR2 memory technology
- 2 x DDR2 DIMM slots
- Supports DDR2 800/667 non-ECC, un-buffered memory
- Max. capacity of system memory: 8GB*

that means you can either use 2x 667 MHz or 2x 800 MHZ DDR2 memory, and no you can't mix them.

Comment: The main board is ASROCK G31M-S

Comment: DIMM packaging was also used with EDO and VCRAM memory, although only common in workstation machines.  (I'm just a fountain of useless knownledge!)